# Linking Buttons and onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm making a randomizing movie app where i have two buttons called decade and genre. Both of the buttons are supposed to output movies  that fall in that category. I'm having a hard time understanding how to make those buttons display those movies. For example, the category (genre) action movies should display action movies and (decade) 1990's should display movies from the 90's. I also want to link those two buttons that way, if you want horror movies from the 80's it output's, horror movies from the 80's.

P.S useEffect is suppose to be at the top

````
         const filteredList = movies.filter(movie => {
         if(genre & decade) {
           return movie.genre_ids === genre && movie.release_date === decade
          } else if (genre) {
            return genre
          } else if (decade) {
          return decade
        } else {
          return true
        }
      })
      setMovies(filteredList)
    },[])


 const [genre, setGenre] = useState()
 const [decade, setDecade] = useState()

return (
    <div className="Genre">
      <DropdownButton title="Genres">
        <Dropdown.Item id="27" onClick={() => setGenre()}>Horror</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item id="28" onClick={() =>"setGenre()"}>Action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item id="35" onClick={() =>"setGenre()"}>Comedy</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item id="10751" onClick={() =>"setGenre()"}>Family</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item id="10749" onClick={() =>"setGenre()"}>Romance</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item id="18" onClick={() =>"setGenre()"}>Drama</Dropdown.Item>
      </DropdownButton>
    </div>



 <div className="decade">
      <Dropdown>
        <div className="App container">
          <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" onSelect={handleDecade}>
            Choose Decade
          </Dropdown.Toggle>

          <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => "1980"}>1980s</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => "1990"}>1990s</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => "2000"}>2000s</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => "2010"}>2010s</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => "2010"}>2020s</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </div>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming if neither Genre nor Decade is selected, you return the full movie list.

I see four issues so far with the code you have given.

1 -> In the Genres onclick Handler it should be something like this:

```
 <Dropdown.Item id="27" onClick={() => setGenre('Horror')}>Horror</Dropdown.Item>
```

where your passing in the value 'Horror' to the setGenre

2 -> In the decade onClick handler, you probably want to do the same thing, call setDecade with the appropriate value:
<Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDecade("1980s")}>1980s</Dropdown.Item>

3 -> You have two dropdowns and to set methods,setGenre and setDecade, however you are treating them differently, using an  onSelect={} handler for the decade an no onSelect handler for the genre,   probably if they are both dropdowns that set state, you can be consistent with how you set the state vs differently per dropdown.

4 -> in your movies.filter(movie => {} )
filter function you want to filter on genre and decade  matches

```
movie => {
         if(genre & decade) {
           // same as you have but used genre_id instead of genre_ids. 
           // if it really is genre_ids (a plural for a singular value)
           // that seems like a code smell)
           // or if genre_ids is a collection then you will need to use
           // something like includes.
           return movie.genre_id === genre && movie.release_date === decade
          } else if (genre) {
            return movie.genre_id === genre.   // filter match here
          } else if (decade) {
            return movie.release_date === decade // filter match here
        } else {
           // same as you have
          return true
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but just one question. Do i keep movies.filter or remove it?

Comment: keep it,    I was just showing the closure/function in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {

    const [genre, setGenre] = useState<string>('');
    const [decade, setDecade] = useState<string>('');
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<{ genre_ids: string, release_date: string }[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const filteredList = movies.filter(movie => {
            if (genre && decade) {
                return movie.genre_ids === genre && movie.release_date === decade
            } else if (genre) {
                return genre
            } else if (decade) {
                return decade
            } else {
                return true
            }
        })
        setMovies(filteredList)
    }, [])


    return (
        <>
            <div className="Genre">
                <DropdownButton title="Genres">
                    <Dropdown.Item id="27" onClick={() => setGenre("27")}>Horror</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id="28" onClick={() => setGenre("28")}>Action</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id="35" onClick={() => setGenre("36")}>Comedy</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id="10751" onClick={() => setGenre("10751")}>Family</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id="10749" onClick={() => setGenre("10749")}>Romance</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id="18" onClick={() => setGenre("18")}>Drama</Dropdown.Item>
                </DropdownButton>
            </div>


            <div className="decade">
                <Dropdown>
                    <div className="App container">
                        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" onSelect={handleDecade}>
                            Choose Decade
                        </Dropdown.Toggle>

                        <Dropdown.Menu>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDecade("1980")}>1980s</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDecade("1989")}>1990s</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDecade("2000")}>2000s</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDecade("2010")}>2010s</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setDecade("2020")}>2020s</Dropdown.Item>
                        </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </div>
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```